# Can a template template parameter default reference other template type parameters?

Tags: c++, templates, template-templates

I'm trying to do something like the following:

```
template <typename T>
struct A
{
    template <typename U>
    struct AA
    {
    };
};

template <typename V, template <typename> class W = A<V>::AA> // Causes C3202
struct B
{
};
```

But the Visual Studio 2010 compiler spits out:

**error C3202: 'AA' : invalid default argument for template parameter '', expected a class template**

If I replace B with the following template:

```
// Replace "T" with "int"
template <typename V, template <typename> class W = A<int>::AA>
struct B
{
};
```

the code compiles fine, but isn't what I want.  If the original isn't legal C++, is there an alternative that provides a similar interface for users of the "B" template?

Comment: This works on VS 2013.

Comment: What type does `template <typename>` ref to?

Comment: @Surt its how to declare templates as template arguments. It tells the compiler `class W` is a template class type, not just some arbitrary type.

Comment: @DarkFalcon So VS 2013 has a bug. This is not a standard-compliant code.

Comment: @Constructor: Yes. It also accepts the correct syntax. I had initially recommended that in an answer but deleted it because of the VS 2010 issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your definition of "similar", you could change your `B` template definition into

```
template <typename V, typename W = A<V>>
struct B
{
};
```

and inside struct `B`, you can access the inner template as

```
W::template AA< some_type >
```

Your users would, however, need to provide the AA-like template wrapped in a class, just as your `struct A`.

You could also lower your requirements on compiler compatibility and require MSVC 2013+.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is not a valid C++ code. See the quotes below.

---

#### C++03

> **14.2 Names of template specializations [temp.names]**
>
> *14.2/4*
>
> When the name of a member template specialization appears after `.` or `->` in a *postfix-expression*, or after *nested-name-specifier* in a *qualified-id*, and the postfix-expression or qualified-id explicitly depends on a template-parameter (14.6.2), the member template name must be prefixed by the keyword `template`. Otherwise the name is assumed to name a non-template.
>
> *14.2/5*
>
> If a name prefixed by the keyword `template` is not the name of a member template, the program is ill-formed. [*Note:* the keyword `template` may not be applied to non-template members of class templates.] Furthermore, names of member templates shall not be prefixed by the keyword `template` if the *postfix-expression* or *qualified-id* does not appear in the scope of a template. [*Note:* just as is the case with the `typename` prefix, the `template` prefix is allowed in cases where it is not strictly necessary; i.e., when the expression on the left of the `->` or `.`, or the *nested-name-specifier* is not dependent on a *template-parameter*.]

---

#### C++11

> **14.2 Names of template specializations [temp.names]**
>
> *14.2/4*
>
> When the name of a member template specialization appears after `.` or `->` in a *postfix-expression* or after a *nested-name-specifier* in a *qualified-id*, and the object expression of the *postfix-expression* is type-dependent or the *nested-name-specifier* in *the qualified-id* refers to a dependent type, but the name is not a member of the current instantiation (14.6.2.1), the member template name must be prefixed by the keyword `template`. Otherwise the name is assumed to name a non-template.
>
> *14.2/5*
>
> A name prefixed by the keyword `template` shall be a *template-id* or the name shall refer to a class template. [ *Note:* The keyword `template` may not be applied to non-template members of class templates. *— end note* ] [ *Note:* As is the case with the `typename` prefix, the `template` prefix is allowed in cases where it is not strictly necessary; i.e., when the *nested-name-specifier* or the expression on the left of the `->` or `.` is not dependent on a *template-parameter*, or the use does not appear in the scope of a template. *— end note* ] [ *Example:*
>
> ```
> // ...
>
> template <class T> struct B {
>   template <class T2> struct C { };
> };
>
> // OK: T::template C names a class template:
> template <class T, template <class X> class TT = T::template C> struct D { };
>
> D<B<int> > db;
> ```
>
> *— end example* ]

---

#### Standard-compliant code

So the correct syntax in this situation is:

```
template <typename T>
struct A
{
    template <typename U>
    struct AA
    {
    };
};

template <typename V, template <typename> class W = A<V>::template AA>
//                                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^
struct B
{
};
```

Unfortunately *VC2010* doesn't understand the valid syntax, too.